# How could i pass parameters to method in a controller through jquery ajax calls

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-web-api

I am working on asp.net web api. I am trying to make a call to controller(Security) using jquery ajax calls. I have a method in my controller with 3 parameters like,

```
public WebRequest GetRequest(string method,string type,string endpoint)
        {
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa=new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        var request = WebRequest.Create(endpoint);
        request.Method = method;
        request.ContentType = type;
        UnicodeEncoding enc = new UnicodeEncoding();
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization-Token", RSAClass.StringConverter(RSAClass.RSAEncrypt(enc.GetBytes("User1"), rsa.ExportParameters(false), false)));
        return request;
}
```

and i am making a jquery ajax call like,

```
CreateRequest("GET", "application/json;charset=utf-8", "http://localhost:49847/api/Security", function (request) { alert("Hello"); });  


function CreateRequest(method, type, endpoint, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "api/Security",
            data: { method: method, type: type, endpoint: endpoint }, 
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            statusCode: {
                200: function (request) {
                    callback(request);
                }
            }
        });
```

and also i have customfilterattribute class to validate authorization token like,

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            string token;
            try
            {
                token = actionContext.Request.Headers.GetValues("Authorization-Token").First();
            }
            catch
            {
                actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest) { Content = new StringContent("missing authorization token") };
                return;
            }
            try
            {
                RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
                UnicodeEncoding enc = new UnicodeEncoding();
                AuthUsersRepository.GetAllUsers().First(x => x.Name ==enc.GetString(RSAClass.RSADecrypt(RSAClass.ByteConverter(token), RSA.ExportParameters(true), false)));
                base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
            }
            catch
            {
                actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden) { Content = new StringContent("Unauthorized User") };
                return;
            }
        }
```

when iam making first request it asking me for authorization token. and also showing null values in the 3 parameters(method,type,endpoint). guide me.

Answer (score 2):

You need this:

```
data: { 'method': method, 'type': type, 'endpoint': endpoint },
```

This passes the values in the request, although in your example I'm not sure why you would need to pass endpoint as a parameter to the method if its value is the URL of the controller / action?

Comment: @Aliostad you can pass data in a GET or POST. The documentation states that the data will be added to the querystring for a GET. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks. Can you please update your post so I can change my -1 to +1?

Comment: Just any update would do. SO does not allow me to change mu upvote downvote after a few minutes.

Comment: @Aliostad I've given it a go!

Answer (score 0):

You either need to

1) change your GET to POST the data as JSON. GET cannot have content.
  2) Pass the data as query string parameters

If I am to do it myself, I would go for case 2:

```
http://localhost:49847/api/Security?method=someMethod&type=someType&endpoint=someendpoint
```

Since this is security related, **it has to be HTTPS**.

But I *would not do it myself*, instead use what security experts have developed: "Thinktecture.IdentityModel.40"

https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityModel.40

Comment: You don't need to convert to a POST or manually write the querystring yourself. Check the jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/